# Get timestamp from date string without timezone and timezone name apart

Tags: javascript, timezone

I have a dateTime string in this (bad, I know) format coming from an external API:

```
const startDate = '2/13/2020 15:00';
```

and the timezone name:

```
const timezoneName = 'America/New_York';
```

Which means that the dateTime is `2/13/2020 15:00` in `New York`.

Any idea for an elegant way to get timestamp (or JavaScript date object)?

I don't mind using `moment.js` or/and `moment-timezone` if it helps.

Comment: That doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moment and Moment-Timezone are for legacy code.

For new applications, the Moment team recommends [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/).

```
const startDate = '2/13/2020 15:00';
const timezoneName = 'America/New_York';

const dateTime = luxon.DateTime.fromFormat(startDate, 'M/d/yyyy HH:mm',
                                           { zone: timezoneName });
const utcDateTime = dateTime.toUTC();
const s = utcDateTime.toISO();

console.log(s); //=> "2020-02-13T20:00:00.000Z"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using moment-timezone should work:

```
const moment = require('moment-timezone');
const t = moment.tz("2/13/2020 15:00", "MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm","America/New_York");
console.log(t.toISOString()); // Prints '2020-02-13T20:00:00.000Z'
```